# wiringPiISR: No such file or directory

Tags: c, interrupt, wiringpi, orange-pi

I'm trying to use interrupts on my Orange Pi Plus H3. I've dowloaded WiringOP from [here](https://github.com/WereCatf/WiringOP) and installed it.

But when I'm running program, I got the message:

**gpio: Unable to open GPIO export interface: No such file or directory
wiringPiISR: unable to open /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value: No such file or directory**

I've found a lot of similar problems but no one solution does not fit me. For example make changes in /boot/config.txt, but in my /boot/ dir I haven't got config.txt file etc.

Are there any ways to solve this?

And here is the code I've tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// WPi 7 to PA7, ie. Physical OPi-pin 29||WPi 8 to PA8, ie. Physical OPi-pin 31||WPi 9 to PG08 OPi-pin 32||
// WPi 10 to PA09 OPi-pin 33|| WPi 12 to PPA10 OPi-pin 35  || WPi 15 to PG06 OPi-pin 38                     
#define BUTTON_PIN 8

// the event counter
volatile int eventCounter = 0;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

void myInterrupt(void) {
  eventCounter++;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void) {

  // sets up the wiringPi library
  if (wiringPiSetup () < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to setup wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno));
    return 1;
  }
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pullUpDnControl (BUTTON_PIN, PUD_UP) ;

  if ( wiringPiISR (BUTTON_PIN, INT_EDGE_FALLING, &myInterrupt) < 0 ) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to setup ISR: %s\n", strerror (errno));
    return 1;
  }

  // display counter value every second.
  while ( 1 ) {
    //  printf( "%d\n", eventCounter );
    if (eventCounter != 0) {
      system("systemctl suspend");
      //printf("Error!!!");
    }

    eventCounter = 0;
    delay( 100 ); // wait 0.1 second
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My system is Lubuntu 15.04 using Loboris' modified kernel.

Comment: My system is Lubuntu 15.04 from Loboris

Comment: Info such as the system you're using should go into the question itself, rather than in the comments. I edited it for you. BTW, can some mod delete these two comments, please?

Answer (score 1):

Well. After a long time working with OrangePI solution has been found.

The only way to use interrupts on Orange Pi is installing [Armbian](http://www.armbian.com/orange-pi/). Then install [this version of WiringOP](https://github.com/WereCatf/WiringOP) and finally clone this:   https:.//github.com/ua3nbw/gpiokey

There will be **wpi.c** file. Compile it using **gcc** and make interrupts on the pin you choose (default - pin 8).

Unfortunately, my Orange is shutting down 5 seconds after first interrupt. Maybe later I'll find the way to fix this.

Comment: Fix: Use "gpio export [pin num]" before using interrupts.